# How to handle focus on a custom actor in Unreal Engine?

Tags: selection, unreal

I created a custom actor, placed it on my scene and selected it.

When I press "F" to focus on it, the camera zoom back very far from the scene, probably because I didn't implement the method supposed to return the bounding box of my actor.

How can I do that?

**Update**

I implemented a custom component which delegates all drawing functions to an internal `ULineBatchComponent` member. I unregistered this `ULineBatchComponent` member. The custom component is not even attached to the actor root component.

But its bounding box is still taken into account when focusing on the actor.

*UPBLineBatchComponent.h*

```
UCLASS()
class UPBLineBatchComponent : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()
public:
    virtual FBoxSphereBounds CalcBounds(const FTransform& LocalToWorld) const;
    void SetTransform(const FTransform &Transform);
    virtual void DrawLine(...);
    virtual void DrawPoint(...);
    void Flush();
    ULineBatchComponent* LineBatchComponent;
    FBox LocalBounds;
};
```

*UPBLineBatchComponent.cpp*

```
UPBLineBatchComponent::UPBLineBatchComponent( const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer )
        : Super( ObjectInitializer )
{
    LineBatchComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<ULineBatchComponent>(TEXT("LineBatcher"));
    LineBatchComponent->UnregisterComponent();
    LocalBounds = FBox(0);
    LineBatchComponent->Bounds = FBoxSphereBounds(EForceInit::ForceInitToZero);
}

FBoxSphereBounds UPBLineBatchComponent::CalcBounds(const FTransform& LocalToWorld) const
{
    LineBatchComponent->Bounds = FBoxSphereBounds(LocalBounds.TransformBy(LocalToWorld));
    return FBoxSphereBounds(LocalBounds.TransformBy(LocalToWorld));
}

void UPBLineBatchComponent::SetTransform(const FTransform& Transform)
{
    LocalBounds = LocalBounds.TransformBy(Transform);
    LineBatchComponent->Bounds = FBoxSphereBounds(LocalBounds);

    bool bDirty = false;
    for (FBatchedLine& Line : LineBatchComponent->BatchedLines)
    {
        Line.Start = Transform.TransformPosition(Line.Start);
        Line.End = Transform.TransformPosition(Line.End);
        bDirty = true;
    }

    for (FBatchedPoint& Point : LineBatchComponent->BatchedPoints)
    {
        Point.Position = Transform.TransformPosition(Point.Position);
        bDirty = true;
    }

    for (FBatchedMesh& Mesh : LineBatchComponent->BatchedMeshes)
    {
        for (FVector& Vert : Mesh.MeshVerts)
        {
            Vert = Transform.TransformPosition(Vert);
            bDirty = true;
        }
    }

    if (bDirty)
    {
        LineBatchComponent->MarkRenderStateDirty();
    }
}

void UPBLineBatchComponent::DrawLine(const FVector &Start, const FVector &End, const FLinearColor &Color, uint8 DepthPriority, float Thickness, float LifeTime)
{
    LineBatchComponent->DrawLine(Start, End, Color, DepthPriority, Thickness, LifeTime);
    LocalBounds += Start;
    LocalBounds += End;
    LineBatchComponent->Bounds = FBoxSphereBounds(LocalBounds);
}

void UPBLineBatchComponent::DrawPoint(const FVector &Position, const FLinearColor &Color, float PointSize, uint8 DepthPriority, float LifeTime)
{
    LineBatchComponent->DrawPoint(Position, Color, PointSize, DepthPriority, LifeTime);
    LocalBounds += Position;
    LineBatchComponent->Bounds = FBoxSphereBounds(LocalBounds);
}

void UPBLineBatchComponent::Flush()
{
    LineBatchComponent->Flush();
    LocalBounds = FBox(0);
    LineBatchComponent->Bounds = FBoxSphereBounds(EForceInit::ForceInitToZero);
}
```

**Update 2**

If I use

```
LineBatchComponent = NewObject<ULineBatchComponent>();
```

instead of

```
LineBatchComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<ULineBatchComponent>(TEXT("LineBatcher"));
```

I can focus properly on the actor, but I can't see the lines anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never experienced the problem you're describing with any custom actor types. You shouldn't need to do anything explicitly, or implement any methods, yourself.

The "focus" command is handled in [EditorServer.cpp](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/release/Engine/Source/Editor/UnrealEd/Private/EditorServer.cpp) (the link requires access to Epic's private Unreal Engine GitHub, which can be obtained by registering an account with Epic); specifically `UEditorEngine::MoveViewportCamerasToActor`.

This method computes a bounding box for the viewable region based on the bounding boxes of the individual selected actors and their components.

Based on your problem description, it is likely that your actor, or one of its components, has an improperly initialized or overly-large bounding box assigned. The other possibility would be that your actor has *no* components, and is configured such that all other code paths computing the bounding box are skipped (certain types of actors, et cetera), resulting in a zero box.

However the subsequent call that actually focuses the viewport on a box will early-out if given a zero box, so it's quite likely the case is the first one: one of your actor's components has an overly-large or malformed non-zero bounding box.

Comment: Yes, I didn't investigate it yet, but I think one of my component returns a huge bounding box. I strongly suspects UBatchLineComponent. I will check  this.

Comment: Yes `UBatchLineComponent::CalcBounds()` (implementation [here](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/97c8d3ef55e869e17ef149903eae2a33101381c9/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/Components/LineBatchComponent.cpp#L353)) returns the biggest bounds possible. And I can't find any way to fix that. I tried to make my custom `UBatchLineComponent` by extending it, but I get [link errors](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118747/link-errors-when-extending-ubatchlinecomponent-in-unreal-engine).

Comment: Another option might be to unregister the component, as the bounding box computation skips unregistered components.

Comment: It still does not work, I edited my question.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on the MoveViewportCamerasToActor function and see where it goes wrong?

Comment: Yes, it collects all components ([here](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/97c8d3ef55e869e17ef149903eae2a33101381c9/Engine/Source/Editor/UnrealEd/Private/EditorServer.cpp#L4593)) and get their bounds with `PrimitiveComponent->Bounds.GetBox();`.

Comment: And is the right bounding box assigned to Bounds at that point? Or is it still a large one. It's possible that your code to compute the bounds correctly hasn't been called yet, or that you must explicitly set the Bounds member on your new component (not just the line batch component you're holding).

Comment: The bounds are set to biggest bounds possible on `ULineBatchComponent::CalcBounds()` which is called every frame, so there is no way to change `ULineBatchComponent::Bounds`. The problem is on `ULineBatchComponent::Bounds`, my custom component has correct bounds. The only solution I see is to stop using `ULineBatchComponent`, and [use](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/97c8d3ef55e869e17ef149903eae2a33101381c9/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Public/DrawDebugHelpers.h#L13) `DrawDebugLine()` but I will have to handle groups of lines manually (to create/delete entire groups of lines).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37467/discussion-between-josh-petrie-and-arthur-sw).