# Why do I get link errors when extending UBatchLineComponent in UE?

Tags: unreal

I got some link errors when extending `UBatchLineComponent` this way:

```
UCLASS(MinimalAPI)
class UPBLineBatchComponent : public ULineBatchComponent
{
    GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()
public:
    virtual void UpdateBounds();
    virtual FBoxSphereBounds CalcBounds(const FTransform& LocalToWorld) const override;
    void SetTransform(const FTransform &Transform);
    FBoxSphereBounds LocalBounds;
};
```

It gave me those errors:

```
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class FPrimitiveSceneProxy * __cdecl ULineBatchComponent::CreateSceneProxy(void)" (?CreateSceneProxy@ULineBatchComponent@@UEAAPEAVFPrimitiveSceneProxy@@XZ)  C:\Users\Yvain\Documents\ProBuilder\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\Module.ProBuilderPlugin.2_of_2.cpp.obj    ProBuilder
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class FPrimitiveSceneProxy * __cdecl ULineBatchComponent::CreateSceneProxy(void)" (?CreateSceneProxy@ULineBatchComponent@@UEAAPEAVFPrimitiveSceneProxy@@XZ)  C:\Users\Yvain\Documents\ProBuilder\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\ProBuilderPlugin.generated.cpp.obj    ProBuilder
Error   9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ULineBatchComponent::ApplyWorldOffset(struct FVector const &,bool)" (?ApplyWorldOffset@ULineBatchComponent@@UEAAXAEBUFVector@@_N@Z) C:\Users\Yvain\Documents\ProBuilder\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\Module.ProBuilderPlugin.2_of_2.cpp.obj    ProBuilder
Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ULineBatchComponent::ApplyWorldOffset(struct FVector const &,bool)" (?ApplyWorldOffset@ULineBatchComponent@@UEAAXAEBUFVector@@_N@Z) C:\Users\Yvain\Documents\ProBuilder\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\ProBuilderPlugin.generated.cpp.obj    ProBuilder
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ULineBatchComponent::DrawLine(struct FVector const &,struct FVector const &,struct FLinearColor const &,unsigned char,float,float)" (?DrawLine@ULineBatchComponent@@UEAAXAEBUFVector@@0AEBUFLinearColor@@EMM@Z) C:\Users\Yvain\Documents\ProBuilder\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\Module.ProBuilderPlugin.2_of_2.cpp.obj    ProBuilder
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ULineBatchComponent::DrawLine(struct FVector const &,struct FVector const &,struct FLinearColor const &,unsigned char,float,float)" (?DrawLine@ULineBatchComponent@@UEAAXAEBUFVector@@0AEBUFLinearColor@@EMM@Z) C:\Users\Yvain\Documents\ProBuilder\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\ProBuilderPlugin.generated.cpp.obj    ProBuilder
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ULineBatchComponent::DrawPoint(struct FVector const &,struct FLinearColor const &,float,unsigned char,float)" (?DrawPoint@ULineBatchComponent@@UEAAXAEBUFVector@@AEBUFLinearColor@@MEM@Z)   C:\Users\Yvain\Documents\ProBuilder\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\Module.ProBuilderPlugin.2_of_2.cpp.obj    ProBuilder
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ULineBatchComponent::DrawPoint(struct FVector const &,struct FLinearColor const &,float,unsigned char,float)" (?DrawPoint@ULineBatchComponent@@UEAAXAEBUFVector@@AEBUFLinearColor@@MEM@Z)   C:\Users\Yvain\Documents\ProBuilder\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\ProBuilderPlugin.generated.cpp.obj    ProBuilder
Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ULineBatchComponent::TickComponent(float,enum ELevelTick,struct FActorComponentTickFunction *)" (?TickComponent@ULineBatchComponent@@UEAAXMW4ELevelTick@@PEAUFActorComponentTickFunction@@@Z)   C:\Users\Yvain\Documents\ProBuilder\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\Module.ProBuilderPlugin.2_of_2.cpp.obj    ProBuilder
Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl ULineBatchComponent::TickComponent(float,enum ELevelTick,struct FActorComponentTickFunction *)" (?TickComponent@ULineBatchComponent@@UEAAXMW4ELevelTick@@PEAUFActorComponentTickFunction@@@Z)   C:\Users\Yvain\Documents\ProBuilder\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\ProBuilderPlugin.generated.cpp.obj    ProBuilder
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ULineBatchComponent` is not fully-exported out of the engine module, so you can't subclass it like that (the symbols you are getting link errors for are not tagged with `ENGINE_API`, so they don't get exported, so they cannot be found at link time).

A better solution to this problem is to create your own component that *delegates* to a `ULineBatchComponent` member for all functionality except that which you're trying to alter (based on your [other question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118708/how-to-handle-focus-on-a-custom-actor-in-unreal-engine), this is the bounding box computation).

You *could* also modify the engine source code to expose the type (remove `ENGINE_API` from all members of `ULineBatchComponent` and added it to the class itself, remove `MinimalAPI` from the `UCLASS` macro). This is probably a recipe for long-term pain, though.